# How to build URL path with Request Param inside it with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf and I want my link to be:
http://localhost:8080**/item?id=1/comments**

I've tried this option:

```
<a th:href="@{item#/comments(id=${item.id})}" th:text="${item.title}"></a>
```

and it gives me:
http://localhost:8080**/item?id=1#/comments**
But the symbol **`#`** is redundant.

I'm not sure I receive it properly in my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/item/comments")
public String showItemComments(@RequestParam Long id, Model model) {
    // do something...
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're trying to use path parameters inside query parameters. That doesn't make much sense. Just use `/items/1/comments`. Once you start the querystring with `?`, you can't add path parameters anymore.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, I achieved the solution by changing the controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/item/comments/{id}")
public String showItemComments(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
}
```